# Selector for two tags in the function. find () JQUERY/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following script

```
 var code = $('textarea[name=message]').val();


if ($('#output').length < 1) {
    $("body").append('<h2>Output</h2><textarea id="output" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea>');
}


var object_code = $('<div/>', {
    html: code
});


object_code.find('value').append("box").html(function (idx, currentHtml) {
    return currentHtml.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + currentHtml.substr(1).toLowerCase();
});

$('#output').val(object_code.html());
```

Inside the textarea input I type some code that looks like this:

```
<data>
  <value> TEXT VALUE 1</value>
</data>
<value> 
TEXT VALUE 2
</value>
<value>
 TEXT VALUE 3
</value>
<value> 
TEXT VALUE 4
</value>
```

And it returns me this

```
<data>
  <value> Text Value 1</value>
</data>
<value> 
Text Value 2
</value>
<value>
 Text Value 3
</value>
<value> 
Text Value 4
</value>
```

He need only apply my role in `<value>` tag that is within the `<date>` tag.
I tried using this code but it does not work :(

```
object_code.find('data value').append("box").html(function (idx, currentHtml) {
        return currentHtml.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + currentHtml.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    });
```

I believe it is a simple problem, Thanks!

Comment: `$('data > value')`  ?

Comment: oh sh... that is in textarea... regexp?

Comment: did it work? didn't know that its possible to use selectors in a textarea...

Comment: @NikTerentyev It gets put inside a `div` in the JS and instantiated.

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/Kyws4/1/, and there's no reason the "direct child" selector would make any difference at all ?

Comment: But .find() should return all the matching elements in the DOM tree.

Comment: Yes work! http://jsfiddle.net/JoaoFelipePego/UpYgA/2/